How to hide directories in Docusaurus path?
I'm trying to build a doc just like the one in this question.
Basically, each document page would have an id (determined by its filename), and it would be accessible from https://example.com/id, regardless of its actual location in the file structure.
Sure, assigning slug to all doc works, but is it possible to achieve the same results by just modifying the project config or adding some custom script without having to add slug front matter to all files?
